# Angular Material Custom Theme Not Applied

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I wrote my custom theme with custom color palettes and I want to use this theme across the whole angular application. When installing angular material, I chose Indigo pink theme just to remove it from angular.json later, but even after doing so and adding 'src/custom-theme' to angular.json's styles array, my app is still using indigo pink theme. Even after restarting local server nothing changed. What could be the problem?

custom-theme.scss

```scss
// Import Angular Material styles
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

// Define custom color palettes
$king-tide-palette: (
  50: #e0f4f9,
  100: #b3e5ef,
  200: #84d4e4,
  300: #5ac3d7,
  400: #43b7cd,
  500: #3babc4,
  600: #379bb1,
  700: #318798,
  800: #2c7380,
  900: #245156,
  contrast: (
    50: rgba(black, 0.87),
    100: rgba(black, 0.87),
    200: rgba(black, 0.87),
    300: rgba(black, 0.87),
    400: rgba(black, 0.87),
    500: white,
    600: white,
    700: white,
    800: white,
    900: white,
    A100: rgba(black, 0.87),
    A200: rgba(black, 0.87),
    A400: white,
    A700: white,
  )
);

$dads-coupe-palette: (
  50: #e7f1f3,
  100: #cadbdd,
  200: #abc1c6,
  300: #8aa8ae,
  400: #72959c,
  500: #59828a,
  600: #4e7379,
  700: #3f5e64,
  800: #324b50,
  900: #22363a,
  contrast: (
    50: rgba(black, 0.87),
    100: rgba(black, 0.87),
    200: rgba(black, 0.87),
    300: rgba(black, 0.87),
    400: rgba(black, 0.87),
    500: white,
    600: white,
    700: white,
    800: white,
    900: white,
    A100: rgba(black, 0.87),
    A200: rgba(black, 0.87),
    A400: white,
    A700: white,
  )
);

$pleasant-pomegranate-palette: (
  50: #fde9e7,
  100: #ffcdbc,
  200: #ffad90,
  300: #ff8c64,
  400: #ff7140,
  500: #ff581c,
  600: #ff5118,
  700: #f24a12,
  800: #e4420d,
  900: #cc3401,
  contrast: (
    50: rgba(black, 0.87),
    100: rgba(black, 0.87),
    200: rgba(black, 0.87),
    300: rgba(black, 0.87),
    400: white,
    500: white,
    600: white,
    700: white,
    800: white,
    900: white,
  )
);

// Define custom palettes with hues 500, 300, 800
$my-primary: mat.define-palette($king-tide-palette, 500, 300, 800);
$my-secondary: mat.define-palette($dads-coupe-palette, 500, 300, 800); 
$my-warn: mat.define-palette($pleasant-pomegranate-palette, 500, 300, 800);

// Define the custom theme
$my-custom-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-primary,
    accent: $my-secondary,
    warn: $my-warn,
  )
));

@include mat.all-component-themes($my-custom-theme);
```

angular.json

```json
{
  "styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    "src/custom-theme.scss"
  ],
  ...
}
```

I tried defining my own custom theme with my own color palettes and I was expecting that all of the existing material components will change their colors according to my custom theme. But they are still using indigo pink theme.

Angular CLI: 16.1.5
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 16.1.6
Firefox 115.0.2

Comment: Did you search your project for all references to `@angular/material/prebuilt-themes`? There should be none left.

Comment: @JSONDerulo I found out that in my angular.json, I actually have 2 styles arrays. Since I am quite new to angular, I only knew about 1 array. So I removed indigo pink from both and it works fine, thank you!

Comment: There might be two styles arrays for different build configurations, for example `development` and `production`.